# Sorting list by values

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a dictionary by values but my code has been erroring. I have three files consisting of scores (in the format "Bob:4", with line breaks between each score.

```
for k in d.keys():
    nlist = d[k][-3:]
    for v in nlist:
        nlist2 = max(nlist)
    sortd = sorted(nlist2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print('{}: {} '.format(k, sortd))
```

This resulted in error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'".

What is causing this error?

Comment: You are sorting `nlist` ? is it a list ?

Comment: as @itzmeontv implies, put a ``print(d)`` in before your for k loop to make sure you have what you think you have

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I'm trying to sort the values of nlist2 (the maximum for each user) and then print them out in a list, with the names next to them (in order of highest to lowest)#

Comment: To be clear: you want to go through the whole list of k in d and find the max of last three entries in d[k]. Then put that in a new dictionary, then sort that and finally print it. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for revised question you could:

```
nlist2 = {k:max(d[k][-3:]) for k in d}
sortd = sorted(nlist2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
for a in sortd:
  print('{}: {} '.format(a[0], a[1]))
```

or use -x[1] if you want highest first

Answer (score 2):

Try it with `sortd = sorted(nlist, key=lambda x: x[1])` and see if that gets what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`sortd = sorted(nlist.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`

This code here use `nlist` but it is a list according to `nlist = d[k][-3:]`

Comment: @Morb The original code have an error msg here, and I just answer with the reason.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mixing up `nlist` and `nlist2` here, he was trying to sort `nlist2.items()` which is an int